# How to sort array of object by property in ng-repeat and not trigger infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a route that resolve data:

```
.state('app.items', {
  url: '/:item',
  views: {
    'content@app': {
      templateUrl: 'app/views/item.html',
      controller: 'ItemsCtrl',
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    items: ['SomeService',
      function (SomeService) {
        return SomeService.getData();
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

and a controller:

```
app.controller('ItemsCtrl', ['items', function (items) {
  this.items = items;

  /**
   * [
   *   {
   *     status: '...',
   *   }, ...
   * ]
   */
}]);
```

I want to sort array in a view by property of object

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | myFilter"></div>
```

by my custom filter(which basicly move removed item to the end):

```
app.filter('myFilter', function () {
  return function (items) {
    return items.sort(function (item) {
      return item.status === 'REMOVED' ? 1 : -1;
    });
  };
});
```

This filter works, but also trigger infinite loop. I was trying to use built in `orderBy` filter(and it works very well), but I have no confidence that removed items will be last(What if i want to add more statuses?). Also, i can't use custom function in controller because this filter will be used multiple times across entire application.

How do I implement `myFilter` to not trigger infinite loop ?

Comment: how do you know it triggers infinite loop ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 I'm getting `[$rootScope:infdig](..)` error in console

Comment: This filter seems to work for me in a regular angular js way, see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24009/ , may be the infinite loop is due to something else ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 This filter works for me also, but only for small lists. If i take larger list(around 100 objects) I'm getting this error.

Comment: @gaurav5430 There is something weird in my code then. I will investigate on my own. Thanks for help!

Comment: @gaurav5430 It's weird. I suppose its because `items` is reference, not copy, and I'm modyfing it somewhere else. I will use `orderBy` till I find right solution.

Comment: also, i am not sure why, but the filter is called twice even while using it in the regular angular way

Comment: Why don't you use orderBy? You can pass a function to it just like you pass a function to sort(). And BTW, a filter isn't supposed to modify the original array. Instead, it's supposed to return a sorted copy. My guess is that you get an infinite loop precisely because you modify the array every time the filter is invoked, and sort() isn't stable (so it can reorder elements even if the elements are already sorted)